# How to set the cursor to end of the TextField? SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield, text-cursor

I want to set the cursor to the end of the TextField like this [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZZKM.jpg)

This is want I have [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsuRg.png)

Can anyone give advice?

Comment: please share the code you have in a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only this time :)

```
    Form {
        HStack {
            Text("User Name")
            TextField("user",text: $user)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Password")
            TextField("password",text: $password)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry that I didn't show my code above ;)

Comment: .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)